# Can I play as Cadence beyond the tutorial?

Tags: cadence-of-hyrule

As you start the game, you play as Cadence for a couple minutes before choosing between Link or Zelda. It appears from that point forward, you play as either of those two characters.

Will I have an opportunity to play as Cadence again in the future, or am I stuck with Link/Zelda for the rest of the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play as Cadence after the tutorial as soon as she joins your group. Before she joins your group, you will encounter her in several caves where she grants you some special technique or a key item.

When you encounter her for the **fourth** time, she will join your group.

> Although the map is random, the cave locations aren't:
>
> - Lake Hylia (lower right corner)
>
>   Gerudo Desert (look for the red banner)
>
>   Death Mountain (Near the Entry to the large area of the Tempel of Storm)
>
>   Lost woods (Right at the entry of the woods)
>
> The cave next to Link's house does not count, though. It only provides the initial shovel and torch for Link and is empty if you start with Zelda.

Comment: Additionally, if you're playing story mode and don't visit every cave, she'll automatically join your group at a certain point in the story, toward the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

You need to find her 4 times during your playthrough, so she joins your team.

Her caves are nearby to the dungeons. You can find her in Lost Woods, Death Mountain, Lake Hylia, and Gerudo Desert.

And when you find her by the fourth time, she will join and you'll be able to use her.

[Source](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/how-to-unlock-cadence-in-cadence-of-hyrule/)

Answer (score 0):

As other answers already say, you will have the ability to pick her in your group and select her using sheika stones as you progress in the story.

But you also have the ability to start a new custom game and select a single character for your run. You won't be able to have any other join your party if you do so, but you will be able to play as Cadence right from the beginning.